# gcloud auth activate-service-account needs access to .ssh folder?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-platform

I run `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=pathtokey`

then I run:

```
gcloud compute scp sdfsdfsdfsdf.txt myinst:/tmp --zone us-east1-b
```

And I get this error:

```
WARNING: The PuTTY PPK SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
open C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.ssh\google_compute_engine: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

i don't understand, why it need access to .ssh I just gave it the path to the key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a difference between the *service account key* and the *SSH key* used for an instance.

The service account key lets you access GCP. You need it to set up an SSH key.

The SSH key lets you log into a particular instance. You can only set one up if you have GCP access (for instance, via a service account key). But the SSH program works via SSH keys, so you'll need one set up.

You can change the location where the SSH key is written using the `--ssh-key-file` flag. See the [documentation for `gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) for more information.