# How can I connect VS Code to a GPU instance on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, gpu, remote-server

I'm on a Windows 10 machine. I have GPU running on the Google Cloud Platform to train deep learning models.

Historically, I have been running Jupyter notebooks on the cloud server without problem, but recently began preferring to run Python notebooks in VS Code instead of the server based Jupyter notebooks. I'd like to train my VS Code notebooks on my GPUs but I don't have access to my google instances from VS Code, I can only run locally on my CPU.

Normally, to run a typical model, I spin up my instance on the cloud.google.com Compute Engine interface. I use the Ubuntu on the Windows Subsystem for Linux installation and I get in like this:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=$ZONE jupyter@$INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

I have tried installing the Cloud Code extension so far on VS Code, but as I go through the tutorials, I always sort of get stuck. One error I keep experiencing is that `gcloud` won't work on anything EXCEPT my Ubuntu terminal. I'd like it to work in the terminal inside VS Code.

Alternatively, I'd like to run the `code .` command on my Ubuntu command line so I can open VS Code from there, and that won't work. I've googled a few solutions, but they lead me to these same problems with neither `gcloud` not working, nor `code .` working.

**Edit**: I just tried the Google Cloud SDK installer from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows

and then I tried running `gcloud compute ssh` from the powershell from within VSCODE. This is the new error I got:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\project\python> gcloud compute ssh --zone=$ZONE jupyter@$INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
WARNING: The PuTTY PPK SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) could not parse resource []
```

It still runs from Ubuntu using WSL, I logged in fine. I guess I just don't know entirely enough about how they're separated, what's shared, and what is missing, and to how to get all my command lines using the same stuff.

Comment: It sounds like the errors you're experiencing with the extension should be included in your post, no?

Comment: in wsl terminal from vscode:: "-bash: gcloud: command not found"

Comment: Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/quickstart) the extension?

Comment: Yes, that is it, and I apologize for the quality and missing info. This is my first post and I've tried maybe 30 things and I am not getting any closer. I just reinstalled gcloud for windows. Now gcloud works in my wsl terminal on vscode, but it tells me "gcloud: 221: exec: python not found"

Comment: Is it possible to do without messing with the terminal? From glancing at that page it seems practically everything is done in the GUI. Also, are you using a virtual environment or similar?

Comment: Maybe, but it seems a bit different than what I usually do. The normal flow is just to run a jupyter notebook on a GPU instance. I ssh into the GPU instance so that I can run a web server. When I type in local host, that's how I browse my jupyter notebooks that are saved on the google GPU instance. My entire desire now is to use that GPU with VS Code. I just want to access those same files I guess from VS code and edit from the GPU instance. Not so straightforward apparently.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean. This is a strange issue.

Comment: This might be useful? https://cloud.google.com/python/setup Haven’t read it all yet, will update later.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your ssh key paths are configured correctly for your Ubuntu terminal but not for the VS Code one. If your account is not configured to use [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access), with which Compute Engine stores the generated key with your user account, local SSH keys are needed. SSH keys are specific to each instance you want to access and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#where_ssh_keys_are_located) is where you can find them. Once you have find them you can specify their path using the [--ssh-key-file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--ssh-key-file) flag.

Another option is to use [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) as I have mentioned before.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487573/gcloud-auth-activate-service-account-needs-access-to-ssh-folder) you have another thread with a similar problem than yours.